# Laravel: how to use short variable name with language files in blades and controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to language files:

/resources/lang/en/account/login.php

```
return [
    'text_login' => 'Login',
    'text_register' => 'Register',
    'error_login' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
];
```

/resources/lang/zh-tw/account/login.php

```
return [
    'text_login' => '登入',
    'text_register' => '註冊',
    'error_login' => '帳號或密碼輸入錯誤',
];
```

/resources/views/welcome.blade.php

```html
<a href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('account/login.text_login') }}</a>
<a href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('account/login.text_register') }}</a>
```

This works. But too long, I wish to make it shorter.
change this

```
{{ __('account/login.text_login') }}
```

to

```
{{ $text_login }}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It's unclear what your actual question is. Please see [ask] and try to be as clear as possible about what you want to do, what you have tried and what results you get.

Comment: At the begging I said what I have tried, according to the laravel document about localization. Then I said, the usage {{ __('account/login.text_login') }} is too long. I wish to use {{ $text_login }}. So my question is simple, how to this? Is it possible?

Comment: "This works. But too long." is not very clear. I had to hunt for this question and then try and figure out what you mean. What  is too long? The parameter? The resulting String? Be as clear as possible. Also, a question like "is is possible to do things like this?" is something you can answer yourself. Try it. See what the results are. Show your research.

Comment: I modified my question. Hope it's clear.

Comment: It's neither too long nor unreadable. There's no problem. Classic `P.I.C.N.I.C`..

Comment: Given that this is how the examples from https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization show how to do it, I'm inclined to agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution.
In each language, I have sub folders and files.

```
/resources/lang/en  
  common.php  
  /catalog
    category.php
    product.php
    attribute.php
    option.php
  ...
```

common.php

```
<?php

return [
  'text_yes' => 'Yes',
  'text_no' => 'No',
  'text_enabled' => 'Enabled',
  'text_disabled' => 'Disabled',
  'text_none' => ' --- None --- ',
  'text_select' => ' --- Please Select --- ',
  'text_select_all' => 'Select All',
  'text_unselect_all' => 'Unselect All',
  'text_default' => ' <b>(Default)</b>',
  'text_close' => 'Close',
  'text_pagination' => 'Showing %d to %d of %d (%d Pages)',
  'text_loading' => 'Loading....',
  'text_no_results' => 'No results!',
  'text_confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
  'text_home' => 'Home',
];
```

category.php

```
<?php

return [
    'heading_title' => 'Categories',

    'text_list' => 'Category List',
    'text_edit' => 'Edit Category',
    'text_repaire' => 'Repaire Category',
    'text_copy' => 'Copy Category',

    'column_name' => 'Name',
    'column_parent_name' => 'Parent Category',
];
```

In CategoryController,

```
//Language
$langs = Lang::get('common');
foreach ($langs as $key => $value) {
  $data[$key] = $value;
}

$langs = Lang::get('category');
foreach ($langs as $key => $value) {
  $data[$key] = $value;
}

//breadcomb
$data['breadcumbs'][] = array(
  'text' => $data['text_home'],
  'href' => route('admin.dashboard'),
);

$data['breadcumbs'][] = array(
  'text' => $data['heading_title'],
  'href' => route('admin.category.index'),
);
```

I thought my idea was so great!

But there are still problems. For example, the key text_pagination, needs arguments: firstItem, lastItem, totals, which is generated by laravel pagination class.

If I load the language files at the begging of the controller function, there are no $categories->firstItem, $categories->lastItem to let me use sprintf. $categories is generated later.

If the language files are put at the bottom, sometimes we need to use the language variables before that, like validation error message.

Edit:
Put language files at the begging should be ok. Later reset the text_pagination:

```
$data['text_pagination'] = sprintf($data['text_pagination'],   
  $categories->firstItem(), 
  $categories->lastItem(), 
  $categories->total(), 
  $categories->lastPage() );
```